# Why GParted doesn't open?

Tags: kde, gparted

When I open GParted , the icon of GParted appear near cursor for 1 minute, but after that the icon disappears and GParted didn't open

but when I run it on terminal with this instruction

> sudo gparted

GParted opens immediately.

I was had Ubuntu 11.10 and recently installed KDE on it .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bug in gparted (to be precise, the wrapper around it, `gparted-pkexec`). If you run `gparted-pkexec` in the terminal, you'll see something like:

```
No protocol specified
No protocol specified

(gpartedbin:19659): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0
```

Replace the contents of to use `kdesudo` instead of `pkexec` to work around this issue:

```
sudo tee /usr/bin/gparted-pkexec <<'EOF'
#!/bin/sh
kdesudo "/usr/sbin/gparted" "$@"
EOF
```

---

**Update**: this is a [bug in PolicyKit](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=51623) combined with a condition in KDE (`$XAUTHORITY` is not set).

Comment: I entered this instruction in terminal. Even copy them into terminal . but it didn't worked for me :(

Comment: You should see the two lines in the middle coming back unchanged when executing it in the terminal. What happens if you execute `gparted-pkexec` in a terminal after doing this? You should get a password dialog from kdesudo.

Comment: Yeah, I see the two lines but When I run `gparted-pkexec` in terminal, I get this error `/usr/bin/gparted-pkexec: 2: kdesudo: not found`

Comment: Ooh, you have not a full KDE system (Kubuntu). Try substituting "kdesudo" for "gksu" for GNOME.